# Send checkbox value to mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I try everything and I don't know what else to try.
I got this html form and i want to results send on mail.
If anyone knows, can you please help me :) 
Feel free to repaire my code or write a new one.

html code:

```
<form method = "post" action = "formcheck.php">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Lift" > Lift</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Terasa" > Terasa</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Novogradnja" > Novogradnja</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Garaza" > Garaža</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Klima" > Klima</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Internet" > Internet</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Kablovska" > Kablovska</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Telefon" > Telefon</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the PHP code is:

```
<?php

$formdoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Lift')) {
            echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Liftom.</i><br> ';
            }
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Terasa')) {
            echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Terasom.</i><br> ';
            }
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Novogradnja')) {
                echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Novogradnjom.</i><br> ';
            }
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Garaza')) {
                echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Garazom.</i><br> ';
            }
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Klima')) {
                echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Klimom.</i><br> ';
            }
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Internet')) {
                echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Internetom.</i><br> ';
            }
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Kablovska')) {
                echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Kablovskom.</i><br> ';
            }
        if(IsChecked('formDoor','Telefon')) {
                echo 'Odabrali ste nekretninu sa <i>Telefonom.</i><br> ';
            }
    }

    function IsChecked($chkname,$value) {
            if(!empty($_POST[$chkname])) {
                foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval) {
                    if($chkval == $value) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


    //slanje maila
    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/', $mail) === 0) {
        echo "<p><strong>Niste uneli validan Email.</strong></p>".
            "<p>Molimo unesite ispravan Email.</p>";
        exit;
    }


    $subject = "Uspesno ste poslali poruku. Hvala sto koristite nase usluge!";
    $subject = ucwords($subject);

    $mailcontent = "Odabrali ste nekretninu sa: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $formdoor)."\n". //HERE I GOT THE PROBLEM
        "Ime i Prezime: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $ime)."\n".
        "E mail: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $mail)."\n".
        "Mobilni: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $mobilni)."\n".
        "Telefon: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $telefon)."\n".
        "Poruka: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $napomena)."\n";
    $fromaddress = "From: webserver@example.com";

    //poziva mail za slanje
    mail($toaddress, $subject, $mailcontent, $fromaddress);

    if (strlen($mail) < 6) {
        echo "E mail adresa nije ispravna. Molimo, unesite validnu E mail adresu.";
        exit;
    }
?>
```

PHP return me error:
**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\eminent\php\formcheck.php on line 236**

I don't know what else should i do it.

Comment: Which line is 236?

Comment: This line is 236
$mailcontent = "Odabrali ste nekretninu sa: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $formdoor)."\n". //HERE I GOT THE PROBLEM

Comment: Please search how to read post array php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are somewere using $variable_name instead of $variable_name["index"] for an associative or $variable_name[0] for an numeric array. Thats were the error comes from.

Comment: I supposed that. Do you have any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: you said: "This line is 236 $mailcontent = "Odabrali ste nekretninu sa: ".str_replace("\r\n"," ", $formdoor)."\n". //HERE I GOT THE PROBLEM "  so in this line there is only one variable in use.... $formdoor - check what datatype this variable contains

Comment: $formdoor = $_POST['formDoor']; + formDoor[] ...  $formdoor is an array - so you cant use it like str_replace("\r\n"," ", $formdoor) - treat it like an array.

Comment: if you cant do it like this stop using an array as name attribute.. just use name="something1"    name="something2" and so on... so you can process this data with $_POST["something1"] and $_POST["something2".... i've never worked with name="something1[]" tbh.

Comment: to understand why i said that... i dont know how the input data is stored in $_POST when using name="something[]" ... is it an numeric array like $_POST["something1"]["val1","val2","val3","val4"]? or associative $_POST["something1"]["foo" => "val1","foo2" =>"val2","foo3" =>"val3","foo4" =>"val4"]? or is every input overwriting the first index? maybe you have to specify the index like name="something['mail']" and so on. you have to check this. if you debug this you can still use your method ofc.

Comment: Do you want me to sent you whole source code to see it?

Comment: i dont have the time for that tbh. but be aware that knowing how to debug your program is a very important skill if not the most important. you could write a complete debug log for your program so you can follow every step and track every datatype, every return value and so on...